# XML header changing when used parsed with DOM

Tags: java, xml, fileparsing

I am having an input xml file and trying edit some values and output xml file using DOM.
But the header is getting changed in the output xml file.

Input File header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ex:exchange
xmlns:ns1=""
xmlns:ns2=""
xmlns:ns3=""
xmlns:ns4="">
<ex:header>
........
.........
</ex:exchange>
```

but the output header is changing like shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><ex:exchange     xmlns:ns1=""     xmlns:ns2="" xmlns:ns3="" xmlns:ns4="">
<ex:header>
........
.........
</ex:exchange>
```

how to get the format retained?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, there is no mean of breaks in XML. Second, the view depends on the viewer program in that you would like to see the XML file (it recognize the file format or not). Third, the linebreak-sign depends on many things, eq. your opsystem, the used parser program, the parser method, the xsd, etc.

But only knowing of the input and output files, helping you is not easy :)